# With knockoutjs and a template, how can I get the value of an input when the user presses enter?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm having some trouble with this, I'm using a template binding like this:

```
<input type='text' data-bind='event: { keyup: function(data, event) { alert();  } }>
</input>
```

However, I want to alert() the value of the input.

I thoughto that `$(this).val()` would do it, but `this` is actually the ViewModel. I thought it could be something to do with `data`, but I don't know what `data` is other than an object.

Any ideas? I want to get the input so I can read and write to it in the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) is a better solution for Your task?

There is even example of what You need to.

```
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    //create a writeable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.computed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : parseFloat(newValue),
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;

            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue != current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());

    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};

function AppViewModel(one, two) {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({ numeric: 0 });
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(two).extend({ numeric: 2 });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234, 123.4525));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do it is hard to give the best advice, but here is a simple fiddle that captures the typed data and uses an observer to perform the alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hfpB

-- EDIT --

Based on your requirements I've updated my fiddle to change from a direct observer to a custom binding that attaches two event handlers (keypress and blur) to a validate function located on the view model.

http://jsfiddle.net/6hfpB/8/

Comment: I want to get the input and apply some CSS to it in the keyup event, if the event.keyCode is enter and the value is a certain amount. I also want to examine the value, and round it down if they entered a decimal.